# ArcGIS JS API Failed to load feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point, feature-layer

I want to add test feature on my ArcGIS map using feature layer. I create layer using `Graphic` as a source. After a lot of googling I create my point the following way:

```
require([
"esri/Map",
"esri/views/MapView",
"esri/layers/TileLayer",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/Graphic",
"esri/geometry/Point",
"esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
"esri/geometry/SpatialReference",
"esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
"dojo/domReady!"
],
    function (Map, MapView, TileLayer, FeatureLayer, Graphic, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SpatialReference, SimpleRenderer) {
        var map = new Map({
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    url: "https://gis.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/arctic_ps/arctic_basemap/MapServer"
                })
            ]
        });

        var viewSpatialReference = 3995;

        var point = new Point({
            x: 1000000,
            y: -1000000,
            spatialReference: new SpatialReference({ wkid: viewSpatialReference })
        });

        var renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
            symbol: new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
                size: 100000,
                color: "#FF4000",
                outline: {
                    color: [255, 64, 0, 0.4],
                    width: 7
                }
            })
        });
        var graphic = new Graphic({
            geometry: point,
            attributes: {
                id: 0
            }
        });

        var fields = [
            {
                name: "id",
                alias: "id",
                type: "oid"
            }
        ];
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                source: graphic,
                fields: fields,
                objectIdField: "id",
                renderer: renderer,
                spatialReference: {
                    wkid: viewSpatialReference
                },
                geometryType: "point"
        });

        //map.on("load", function () {
              console.log('load event called');
              map.layers.add(featureLayer);
        //});

        var centerPoint = {
            x: 1000000,
            y: -1000000,
            spatialReference: viewSpatialReference
        };

        var viewOptions = {
            container: "map",
            map: map,
            viewingMode: "local",
            spatialReference: viewSpatialReference,
            scale: 12000000,
            center: centerPoint
        };

        var view = new MapView(viewOptions);
    });
```

Map is loading fine, but test point isn't appear. If I use this code, I get two errors in console:

> [esri.layers.FeatureLayer] #load() Failed to load layer (title: 'null', id: '16a2638ea4d-layer-1') TypeError: this.source.load is not a function
>       at Object.r.createGraphicsSource (dojo.js:2178)
>
> [esri.views.LayerViewFactory] Failed to create view for layer 'null, id:16a2638ea4d-layer-1' of type 'feature'. {error: TypeError: this.source.load is not a function at Object.r.createGraphicsSource (https://js.arcgis.com/4.10/dojo/dojo.js:2178:377)}

I think cause of this errors is map is not yet loaded when I create try to create layer. I commented `map.on("load", function (){})` call as if I use it there is no errors in console at all. I research script using browser debugger and find out that function body isn't executed for some reason.

Maybe I miss something in layer creating. I set huge size for marker to exclude possibility, that marker is just small. I also make [example](https://jsfiddle.net/t30ndkzg/5/) in Fiddle for your comfort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your graphics should be wrapped in an array. Simply change

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                source: graphic,
                fields: fields,
                objectIdField: "id",
                renderer: renderer,
                spatialReference: {
                    wkid: viewSpatialReference
                },
                geometryType: "point"
        });
```

to

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                source: [graphic],
                fields: fields,
                objectIdField: "id",
                renderer: renderer,
                spatialReference: {
                    wkid: viewSpatialReference
                },
                geometryType: "point"
        });
```

Next, I'm not sure how familiar you were with the 3.x JS API, but in that map.on("load"... was a common workflow.

I haven't worked with 4.x for a while, but I think you want to apply the same idea, but use the view.when() syntax. Instead of `map.on("load"...` use `view.when(...` after you created the view at the bottom of the script.

working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vgf5cryz

Comment: Thanks, this work for me too. However, `map.on("load", function (){})` call still doesn't execute its body. It's strange that adding marker work without waiting for map loading

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you were with the 3.x JS API, but in that `map.on("load"`... was a common workflow. 

I haven't worked with 4.x for a while, but I think you want to apply the same idea, but use the `view.when()` syntax.

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vgf5cryz/

Instead of `map.on("load"...`

I used `view.when` after you created the view at the bottom of the script.

Comment: I am totally new to ArcGIS JS API, thanks for example. Maybe I will use it, for now I struggle with `GeometryService.project` and `Promise` as my map not in webmercator.